# Answering a hypothesis with R Studio

Tags: r, regression

I have the following hypothesis: If the monthly income is higher, then the job satisfaction increases.

Variables:

```
$ JobSatisfaction: Ord.factor w/ 4 levels: 1 = low, 2 = medium, 3 = high, 4 = very high

$ MonthlyIncome  : int  5993 5130 2090 2909 3468 3068 2670 2693 9526 5237,...
```

With these two variables, I now need to do a regression analysis. Therefore I was suggested to use a dummy coding. If so, can someone please explain me the individual steps I need to take in order to get proper results.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the function `lm` used for regression analyses in R will do the coding internally if one supplies variables as factors. For un ordered factors it will use  treatment contrasts and for ordered factors it will use polynomial contrasts. [Good stuff](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105115/polynomial-contrasts-for-regression). Also [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-and-interpreting-different-contrasts-in-linear-models-in-r/)

Answer (score 1):

This looks rather like a homework question, and if that is the case then having us do your homework for you is a dis-service to you, your classmates, your future employer(s) and others.

If this is not a homework question, then you will still benefit from learning how to do this and interpret the results yourself, but I will include some pointers to steer you in the right direction.

First, you really need to decide what your question is and what background information drives it.

If you think that Job Satisfaction drives Income, or want to use satisfaction to predict income, then regression with dummy variables is appropriate and the `lm` function in R will create dummy variables for you (note RStudio is a GUI for R, RStudio does not do calculations for the regression, rather it passes your commands to R, R does the calculations and sends the results back to RStudio to display).  You should consult a good textbook or class on regression, or a consultant to make sure that you are comfortable with the assumptions that go into the regression model and to understand the results.

If on the other hand you think that income drives/predicts/determines Job Satisfaction (which is what your first line implies), then regular regression (especially with dummy variables) is not appropriate.  More appropriate would be proportional odds logistic regression.  There are packages for R that implement this (MASS and rms being 2 of them), but this is more complicated than linear regression, so you really should consult a consultant, or take additional classes, to fully understand the assumptions and how to interpret the results.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Greg's answer that it is important to decide on your research hypothesis and establish the data and analytic techniques that are relevant for the data needed to test the hypotheses.

That said, regarding the question of dummy coded variables and the `lm()` function, R will automatically create dummy coded variables in `lm()` for independent variables that are factors. As an illustration, we'll use data from the Gross National Income 2014 data set that is included in the `treemap` package.

Null hypothesis: gross national income per capita does not vary significantly by continent

Alternate hypothesis: gross national income per capita varies significantly by continent

R code for this analysis:

```
library(treemap)
data(GNI2014)

# recode continent as a factor 
GNI2014$continent <- as.factor(GNI2014$continent)

# use lm() to regress gross national income on continent
theModel <- lm(GNI ~ continent, data=GNI2014)
summary(theModel)
```

...and the output:

```
> theModel <- lm(GNI ~ continent, data=GNI2014)
> summary(theModel)

Call:
lm(formula = GNI ~ continent, data = GNI2014)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-26991 -11189  -1809   3237  89284 

Coefficients:
                                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    

(Intercept)                          2184       2679   0.815 0.415985    

continentAsia                       13309       3808   3.494 0.000597 ***
continentEurope                     27368       3947   6.934 6.98e-11 ***
continentNorth America              14672       4640   3.162 0.001836 ** 
continentOceania                     9616       5803   1.657 0.099220 .  

continentSeven seas (open ocean)     7863      11045   0.712 0.477454    

continentSouth America               7012       5990   1.171 0.243297    

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 18560 on 181 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2166,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1906 
F-statistic: 8.342 on 6 and 181 DF,  p-value: 5.456e-08
```

As we can see from the regression output, the slopes for Asia, Europe, and North America are positive and significantly different from 0 at the 0.05 level of significance. Note that since it not listed directly, the continent of Africa is accounted for by the intercept. All other slopes are interpreted relative to the intercept.

Since the F-statistic of 8.342 is significant at the 0.05 level, we reject the null hypothesis that per capita gross national income is the same across continents in favor of the alternate hypothesis that is not equal across continents.

Note that this same analysis may be completed with the `aov()` function.

```
theModel <- aov(GNI ~ continent, data = GNI2014)
summary(theModel)
theModel$coefficients
```

...and the output:

```
> summary(theModel)
             Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
continent     6 1.724e+10 2.873e+09   8.342 5.46e-08 ***
Residuals   181 6.234e+10 3.444e+08                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> theModel$coefficients
                     (Intercept)                    continentAsia 
                        2183.958                        13308.595 
                 continentEurope           continentNorth America 
                       27367.505                        14671.875 
                continentOceania continentSeven seas (open ocean) 
                        9616.042                         7862.708 
          continentSouth America 
                        7011.875
```